# Detecting when screen is in portrait or landscape mode and the edges of a screen across device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, screen, screen-orientation

I'm currently investigating how to detect screen mode (portrait or landscape) and also where the edges of different screens are so I can fit a sprite sheet animation right on the edges of the phone. And refit the animation to the correct view.

I looked at the screen orientation API at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation
which is experimental, so I might use that API to check the screen mode, welcoming any other suggestions of course.

My question though is about what tools are available to detect the edges of the screen of a device in javascript. So the animation is visible and positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a web application, you could use the

`window.innerWidth`

`window.innerHeight`

properties to detect the window size of your user and change your animation as you see fit.